# Partitioning a totally ordered set into three subsets according to the order

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory, set-partition

Consider a set $S$, and a total order $R$ over that set.

Part (a)

Given some element $e \in S$, explain why it is possible to partition $S$
into the following three sets:
    $$S_1 = \{ x \in S \mid (x,e) \in R \} $$
    $$\{e\}$$
    $$S_2 = \{ x \in S\mid (e,x) \in R \} $$

*Why can you? I totally lost on this.*

Part (b)

Given a partitioning of $S$ as stated in Part (a), explain why, for any
$e_1 \in S_1$ and $e_2 \in S_2$, we know that both of the following are
true:
    $$(e_1,e_2)     \in R $$
    $$ (e_2,e_1) \not\in R $$

Remember: You cannot use your intuitive understanding of ``less than,''
since the members of $S$ might not be numbers.  Instead, use the formal
definition of a total order, and argue that the statements above must
be true!

*Also how would not using inequalities work?*

Comment: I asked this yesterday and I still have not got anywhere from it.

Comment: And so you deleted and reposted? This isn't how the site is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 2):

The partitioning follows directly from the definition of a total order (specifically, this is a *strict* total order, like < on the integers).  Strict total orders exhibit trichotomy: any pair of objects is either in order one way, or the other, or else it is the same object.  These three categories are exclusive, thus it partitions the set.

For the second part, assume that either case is not true, and apply transitivity of a total order at $e$.

EDIT: When I say "this is a *strict* total order" I am *assuming* that this is what you meant to say because it makes no sense otherwise.  A (non-strict) total order does not imply the set can be partitioned, because it is reflexive (for all $a$, $a R a$ holds) therefore $e$ would be in all three sets and thus would not partition the set.  (Reflexivity follows from antisymmetry and transitivity which are properties of a non-strict total order.)

Comment: So could i say there is some x in S1 that goes to e, then there is only one e element in the Set, and then there is some *different* x value that is present in the second set that immediately follows e?

Comment: Then for the second part since the S is total order, the elements have to be in order.  So Since S1 is before S2 and since e1 $\in$ S1 and e2 $\in S_2$ that e1 comes before e2 in R.  Is that in the right direction?

Comment: Notice that $(e_1, e)$ is in order since everything in the first set is in order with $e$.  Similarly, $(e, e_2)$ is also in order.  Since any kind of order is transitive, this implies $(e_1, e_2)$ is in order.  This works regardless as to which objects you choose.